# Automatically generate UVs for a given 3D model

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d

Is there a tool/command that can automatically unwrap/generate UV for a given 3D model?

We have an .obj file that comes from a 3D camera. But it comes without UVs.

I heard that MeshLab can do it.

Is there a command-line command for MeshLab or a similar command-line tool to achieve this?

I also found https://www.instantuv.org/, but it loses a lot of detail in the process.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of auto meshing alternatives which can generate UVs (most of which will also do auto retopology which if your obj is from a 3D camera you will most likely need pretty badly) and [**MeshLab**](http://www.meshlab.net/), [**MeshMixer**](http://www.meshmixer.com/), [**Instant Mesh**](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/instant-meshes/) all leap to mind. Most **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) tools ([**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), [**Maya**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), [**3DS**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview), [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), [**Cinema 4D**](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/)) have their own discrete UVing toolsets, and many of those now have pre-canned UV unwrap commands - most of which you should be able to invoke from the command line.

The risk you run with auto meshing / auto UV methods is that if your initial geometry isn't already pretty well topologised, the resulting UVs will be... challenging... to work with.

FWIW: [**Instant Mesh**](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/instant-meshes/) is pretty darn amazing, and can help you get some close-to-manually retpologised quickly, which then makes whatever approach you choose for auto UVing far more likely to succeed.

**[Instant UV](https://www.instantuv.org/)** (the link you had provided) looks *very* interesting - I didn't see on the public-facing info anything which led me to conclude that the UVs generated by their auto-UVing SDK were somehow low detail - but I did see that one of the retopology demonstration figurines seemed to push pretty far down the detail scale (the rivets which were fully half-spherical in the original scan mesh had been downsampled so far that they became tetrahedra) however I looked briefly at the online docs for the CLI mesh reduction tool, and it sure *looked* like you could tune the degree of compression - and more crucially, it looked like it had an automated setup for baking normal and colour maps from the high-res mesh to the lower - which depending upon your final use-case for this model might be a huge time saver.

What I didn't see there was whether you can choose tris or quads for remeshing - cos for some of us, quads are far preferred - both for general sub-D work and for ease of animation... but I know that [**Instant Mesh**](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/instant-meshes/) does give me that choice.

Hope some of this helps.